# Form validation and number formatting with Ionic and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to add number formatting and data validation to this input element:

```
<input class="a" type="text" placeholder="Amount" ng-model="data.amount">
```

I would like if:

- Thousand separators were created automatically
- When the user submits and has written text he, submission fails and he get's a warning close to the textbox that says that he needs to write a numerical field

How can I do this in a good way with AngularJS and Ionic?